# Dynamics CRM 4.0 J Script - 'If' statement using statecode

Tags: if-statement, dynamics-crm, dom-events, jscript, onload-event

I am trying to create a simple alert as an `onload` event on the contact entity. However, I only want this to trigger if one of the conditions is that the contact is still active.

I therefore put it the following:

```
if (crmForm.all.statecode.DataValue == 0)    
{    
alert("'Whatever alert I want") ;    
}
```

However, when I load the contact record it errors. Is it not possible to base an 'if' statement on the status.

Comment: No idea what dynamics-crm is but fyi document.all is IE only so if your testing in something else it wont work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is the crmForm.FormType enumeration:

http://mscrm-developer.blogspot.com/2008/09/crm-form-types.html

crmForm.FormType == 4 means the form is deactivated (statecode 1) so you could do something like

```
if (crmForm.FormType != 4) alert("Whatever alert I want");
```

Just be cautious of all the various form types that are out there and make sure you get the alert where you want it.